# How to change the background of a table cell if it meets a requirement with a button

Tags: javascript

> Write a program that dynamically creates a 100x100 table. Each element
> in the table will have a unique number, starting at 1 and increasing
> by 1.
>
> This page will also have a button that will be "Calculate almost prime
> numbers." This button will cause all the cells in the table that have
> “Almost Prime” numbers to have a yellow background.
>
> Almost prime number: it is a number that is only divisible by itself,
> the unit and by a single number that is neither the unit nor itself.

Hello, I am relatively new to the world of JavaScript and I am trying to solve this JavaScript exercise and as you can see the first part is to make a 100x100 table, which I have been able to do, the problem is the second part in which I have to change the background of the cells to the "almost prime numbers"

Here I leave my code, probably many things can be improved apart from finding a solution to putting the background color of the cells, anyway thanks if you can help me.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);

function main() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];


  var tabla = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");




  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    var fila = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var j = 0; j <= 100; j++) {
      var columna = document.createElement("td");
      var numero = document.createTextNode(j + i * 100);
      columna.appendChild(numero);
      fila.appendChild(columna);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(fila);
  }

  tabla.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tabla);
  tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
}

function casiprimos() {

  let contador = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j <= 100; j++) {
      let num = (j + i * 100)
      for (var z = 1; z <= num; z++) {
        let resultado = num % z;
        if (resultado == 0) {
          contador = contador + 1;
        }
      }
      if (contador == 3) {
        // num.setAttribute("style","background-color: yellow;"); ? Idk 
        contador = 0;
      } else {
        contador = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, You're trying to change a table cell background on which you click?

Comment: Being a 100x100 table in which in each cell there is a number that does not repeat, so I have in the cells from 1 to 10,000, only the cells that contain a number with three divisors have to have a yellow background. the "almost prime" condition.

Comment: You can get all the table cell with querySelectorAll() and then loop over them to check if conditions met